# How to run command line in while loop in python

Tags: javascript, python, cmd, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python. I want to run command line in a python script. The program works fine if I put the main body without a loop; however, once I call the cmd in loop in python, there is no responding and cannot print anything. If I delete the `os.system()` the program can work and can print "complete a loop". I tried to add a timer, but it still cannot work.

Python version: 3.7.3
Windows system
Jupyter Notebook

Here is the code

```
       while (some condition):
            with open('search_page.js','w') as out:
                line1 = """
                var page = require('webpage').create(), t, address;
                var fs = require('fs');
                var path = '{}' 
                page.customHeaders={{'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa(‘{}:{}’)}};
                page.open('{}', function(){{console.log(page.content);
                var content = page.content 
                fs.write(path, content, 'w')
                phantom.exit(); }}
                );
                """.format(temporary_webpage, cibc_username, cibc_password, search_url)
                out.write(line1)

            os.system('phantomjs.exe search_page.js')
            print("complete a loop")
```

I also tried to use 'subprocess' to replace "os.system", it also cannot work.

```
            subprocess.call(["phantomjs.exe","search_page.js"])
```

So, how could I solve it?

Comment: Assuming the part inside the loops works correctly, maybe the problem comes from the "spamming" generated by the while loop. Maybe you could try adding a timer, e.g. execute every 10 seconds by adding `time.sleep(10)` at the end of the loop (and importing the time module ofc).

Comment: As a first debugging step, try commenting out the `os.system()` line.  If you do that, do you see the "complete a loop" output?